# Creating std::map with a structure as its key and value

Tags: c++, std

I want to define a static map inside a class, which will have a structure as both it's key and value. I've read that a **'<' operator** is needed to be defined, therefore I've included that definition inside the struct itself(I've randomly defined it as I don't need any comparison anywhere in my program).

The below sample code doesn't compile.The compiler produces a lot of warnings and errors which I don't understand right now. (Please ignore the uninitialized values in the main function):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

struct RJNodeAddress
{
        string m_ip;
        string m_port;
        bool operator<(const RJNodeAddress &l)
        {
                int l_size=l.m_ip.size();
                int r_size=l.m_port.size();
                return (l_size < r_size);
        }
};

struct RJNodeDetails
{
        string m_NodeType;
        int        m_appId;
};

class RJWebsocket
{
public:
static map<RJNodeAddress,RJNodeDetails> m_Nodes;
};

int main()
{
RJNodeAddress l_node;
 RJNodeDetails l_nodeDetails = RJWebsocket::m_Nodes[l_node];

}
```

**Compiler output**

```
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of âconstexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = RJNodeAddress]â:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:491:32:   required from âstd::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = RJNodeAddress; _Tp = RJNodeDetails; _Compare = std::less<RJNodeAddress>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const RJNodeAddress, RJNodeDetails> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = RJNodeDetails; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = RJNodeAddress]â
test.cpp:34:59:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: error: no match for âoperator<â (operand types are âconst RJNodeAddressâ and âconst RJNodeAddressâ)
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
test.cpp:10:14: note: candidate: bool RJNodeAddress::operator<(const RJNodeAddress&) <near match>
         bool operator<(const RJNodeAddress &l)
              ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:10:14: note:   passing âconst RJNodeAddress*â as âthisâ argument discards qualifiers
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:449:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:449:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::pair<_T1, _T2>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:305:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:305:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:343:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:343:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:1142:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:1142:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:1148:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:1148:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:48:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:485:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator<(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)
     operator< (basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:485:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âRJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âstd::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:48:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:491:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator<(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, std::__detail::__idt<std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >)
     operator< (basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:491:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âRJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âstd::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:48:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:497:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator<(std::__detail::__idt<std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)
     operator< (__detail::__idt<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string_view:497:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âRJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âstd::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5892:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5892:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5905:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5905:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:52:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5917:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:5917:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   mismatched types âconst _CharT*â and âRJNodeAddressâ
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:208:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator<(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)
   operator<(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
   ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:208:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst RJNodeAddressâ to âconst std::error_code&â
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:282:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator<(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)
   operator<(const error_condition& __lhs,
   ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:282:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst RJNodeAddressâ to âconst std::error_condition&â
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:808:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Up> constexpr std::__optional_relop_t<decltype ((declval<_Tp>() < declval<_Up>()))> std::operator<(const std::optional<_Tp>&, const std::optional<_Up>&)
     operator<(const optional<_Tp>& __lhs, const optional<_Up>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::optional<_Tp>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:861:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::optional<_Tp>&, std::nullopt_t)
     operator<(const optional<_Tp>& /* __lhs */, nullopt_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:861:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::optional<_Tp>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:866:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> constexpr bool std::operator<(std::nullopt_t, const std::optional<_Tp>&)
     operator<(nullopt_t, const optional<_Tp>& __rhs) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:866:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::optional<_Tp>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:926:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Up> constexpr std::__optional_relop_t<decltype ((declval<_Tp>() < declval<_Up>()))> std::operator<(const std::optional<_Tp>&, const _Up&)
     operator<(const optional<_Tp>& __lhs, const _Up& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:926:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::optional<_Tp>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:932:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Up> constexpr std::__optional_relop_t<decltype ((declval<_Up>() < declval<_Tp>()))> std::operator<(const _Up&, const std::optional<_Tp>&)
     operator<(const _Up& __lhs, const optional<_Tp>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/optional:932:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::optional<_Tp>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:39:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:40,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/array:262:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> bool std::operator<(const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)
     operator<(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __a, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __b)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/array:262:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::array<_Tp, _Nm>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/node_handle.h:40:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:72,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1410:5: note: candidate: template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::tuple<_Tps ...>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
     operator<(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1410:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::tuple<_Tps ...>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:60:0,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:1543:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:1543:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:61:0,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:1397:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:1397:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/map:62:0,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_multimap.h:1062:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_multimap.h:1062:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/string:48:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   âconst RJNodeAddressâ is not derived from âconst std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>â
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: "_The below sample code doesn't compile due to some reasons_" When code doesn't compile, compiler gives you an error message. Please [edit] the question, and copy-paste the error messages, that you get, into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As keys in `std::map` are const your `operator<` method must be const as well:

```
  bool operator<(const RJNodeAddress &l) const
                                        // ^ here
```

it should be const anyway as it does not modify the object but in this case missing it leads to compilation errors.